# How to provide App Icon with Display P3 Color profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, colors

I have a project whose app icon uses the Display P3 color profile.

### Specifications:

```
Color Profile: Display P3
Color Depth: 16 bits / channel
```

- I have verified the above by viewing the information on the Preview app (info on the preview app shows the image details as above).
- I have added the app icon the Assets Catalog and I have specified the Gamut as Display P3 and provided the Display P3 assets.

### Problem:

- However the color of the **app icon** on the iPhone doesn't seem correct.
- The same image when viewed on the iPhone the color is displayed correctly.
- I think somehow the App Icon seems to be not picking the color profile.

### Question:

- How can I make the Display P3 app icon be displayed with the correct colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I’m not sure if XCode is converting the image to sRGB colorspace when it packages the images into the app bundle or if iOS has a bug in the way it displays the icons. However I have tested it by designing an icon that contains two colors: one is srgb red [1,0,0] and the other color is p3 red [1,0,0]. If the icon displays correctly you see two colors. But if it gets converted to srgb then both parts of the icon are the same color. When testing it always shows the same color on both sides.

I have reported this using a support incident and Apple agreed that it was a bug. I also filed a bug report. It would help if other people who have this problem file a duplicate report to bring more attention to this issue.